# Laravel remove objects with duplicate values in array

Tags: php, laravel

My application returns an array of objects and each object contains a **"name"** key which sometimes is repeated in other objects.

How can I filter the duplicates?

**This is an array having duplicates**

```
[
    {"name":"India","id":2,"uid":"1M16"},
    {"name":"Delhi","id":3,"uid":"1M16"},
    {"name":"India","id":4,"uid":"1M16"}
]
```

**The output I want is:**

```
[
    {"name":"India","id":2,"uid":"1M16"},
    {"name":"Delhi","id":3,"uid":"1M16"}
]
```

**And this is how I am getting this array from database.**

```
$results_1 = Sheet::whereIn('uid', $results_1)->select('name', 'id', 'uid')->get();
```

Comment: add your code and other information too.

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon updated question

Comment: Group by `name` in the query will get correct result? `$results_1 = Sheet::whereIn('uid', $results_1)->select('name', 'id', 'uid')->groupBy('name')->get(); `. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct()` if you want a single column. In your case you need `groupBy()` to get the unique values.

```
$results_2 = Sheet::whereIn('uid', $results_1)->select('name', 'id', 'uid')->groupBy('name')->get();
```

> you are using same `$results_1` variable to hold the new values and in `whereIn` clause. consider using different variables.

And to use `groupBy()` you have to change some things in your database config file. in your `config>database.php` file add this lines in mysql configuration.

```
'modes' => [

    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
]
```

And don't forget to clear the cache after changing anything in the config file.

Comment: Surely turning off strict mode is a fudge and the best way is to fix the values you select to use aggregate functions for non group by fields.

Comment: ya i know. i personally use modes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you worried to change the modes in config/database.php which could be risky for all queries you are accessing through laravel you can simply one line above to the specific query where you want to off the strict mode. This answer will help those who are in search to do it without changing the modes globally.

Like this:

```
DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");//this is the trick use it just before your query
$results_2 = Sheet::whereIn('uid', $results_1)->select('name', 'id', 'uid')->groupBy('name')->get();
```